# How to share multicast traffic to many vlans

Tags: linux, freebsd, vlan, multicast, video

I have linux computer , this computer connected with entire my network via zyxel gs-2200.

In this zyxel also connected router with 500 vlans, one by client.

On linux computer i have vlc program that stream multicast ip-tv.

In the same vlan where is my linux box, i can see the tv.

Question is, how to reshare this multicast stream to all vlans?

Who (zyxel, router (freebsd) , or linux box) and how must modify stream to be public for all client vlans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use multicast routing between the VLAN's to make this work.

From what I can tell you'll need to compile the FreeBSD kernel with the MROUTING option, and then use [mrouted](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mrouted&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports).

See the following thread on the official FreeBSD forums for more information:
http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=5875

Comment: i had hope, that l2 zyxel can do that.
but bsd-router ok too. 
tnx.