# How to send multicast traffic from one vlan to 100-500 other

Tags: freebsd, vlan, multicast

In addition to prev question

[How to share multicast traffic to many vlans](https://serverfault.com/questions/322466/how-to-share-multicast-traffic-to-many-vlans/322475#322475)

I recieve answer that solution for my task is mrouted on my freebsd router.

But for now i see this problems:

- mrouted accept only 32 interfaces, but i have 500 vlan interfaces on my router
- mrouted -r , show right about "input" interface

  ```
   8 vlan4055  172.16.20.29    subnet: 172.20.20.0/27      1   1      0   querier leaf

               IGMP querier: 172.20.20.29       (this system)
                Nbr bitmaps: 0x0000000000000000
             pkts/bytes in : 759527/1020304898
             pkts/bytes out: 0/0
  ```

  but looks like something wrong with all other 32 interfaces , i tryed to start vlc on many of them, but still see

  ```
     pkts/bytes in : 0/0
     pkts/bytes out: 0/0
  ```
- I have a lot of warnings in mrouted log:

  ```
   15:57:11.875 warning - sendto to 224.0.0.4 on 10.33.133.126: Invalid argument
   15:57:11.875 warning - sendto to 224.0.0.4 on 10.33.133.190: Invalid argument
  ```

Say me please, is mrouted right answer for my situation, and if Yes how to solve this 3 problems. If No what i must use as replacement for mrouted.

(also i need not bidirectional multicast routing, i always have exactly one input vlan, and 500 for output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mrouted` is the only solution of which I am aware.
In the grand tradition of the BSD family of operating systems: "The source code is there - Feel free to modify mrouted and submit a patch".

(In reality: I can't think of why you need so many vLANs and want to send multicast across all of them.  Either pick and choose, refactor your network to be less mind-bogglingly complex, or invest in dedicated networking gear that can do what you need -- Cisco or Juniper may have something suited to this...)

Comment: Almost -1 for the "Its open source, do it yourself" comment. Not everyone is a programmer, not every programmer is a/wants to be a bsd developer, and not every bsd developer has time for that

Comment: @TheLQ I'll grant that not everyone has the skills to modify software themselves, however the options I provided are, as I said, the only only ones I'm aware of.  Unfortunately sometimes the answer is "If you want it to do that you'll have to hack it yourself (or hire someone to do so)" ; Fortunately it's open-source so you actually have the option.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
After lot of pain, we stop trying mrouted, and still trying refactor the network.